# Centering li items with display:inline that have ul inside

Tags: css, html-lists

Hi I'm looking to set up a centered footer that uses list items with unorganized lists inside of each list item.  If I try using float:left I get them to be inline with each other but it is no longer centered.  The code i currently have looks like this:
css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#box1 {
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#00FF66;
}
#mainList {
list-style-type:none;
text-align:center;
display:inline;
}
.mainLI {
display:inline;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="box1">
<ul id="mainList">
    <li class="mainLI">
        <p>Title</p>
        <ul class="subList">
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mainLI">
        <p>Title</p>
        <ul class="subList">
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's beacuse content is centered by text-align within container, that is 100% width of container as default, but less if it's floating.

Anyways i don't understand what you want to achieve? You want to center list item but float it in the same time? Could you precise yourself more?

Comment: I am trying to make it look like the footer in the grey on this page: [link](http://safari.etrafficers.com)  Thanks!

Comment: Then u shouldn't float elements inside mainList, but mainList itself or any other container, and leave list items as block elements, they will adjust to container size, you m8 want to set width of the ,,column'' since block elements always take 100% of it's container (so width and float of container will help u float the columns)

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#box1 {
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#00FF66;
}
#mainList {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#mainList li, .mainLI p {
    display:inline;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yZW7E/)

Your problem with centering lies in the fact that the parent element in which you are centering children must be a block element. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align)

Comment: Ok so that lines everything up horizontally and centered which makes sense but any ideas on how to make the sub menus be underneath and be vertical instead of horizontal? like the footer in grey on this [page](http://safari.etrafficers.com)